# How to use multiple arrays in foreach statement with php & xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, foreach

I am needing to return multiple values from an xpath query, as shown in the coding below. I have an XML file and simple values in it. I will get the Account Name and Email Address values from the XML using XPath in PHP, and will need to have them echoed as comma separated values. So using the code below, the result would be:

```
Company A,mail@company-a.com
Company B,mail@company-b.com
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $XMLfile = "test.xml";
  $a = 'result/Accounts/row/FL[@val="Account Name"]';
  $e = 'result/Accounts/row/FL[@val="E-mail Address"]';

  $xml = simplexml_load_file($XMLfile);
  $result = $xml->xpath($a);
  $result2 = $xml->xpath($e);
  foreach ($result as $le_result)
  echo $le_result."<br>";
?>
```

and 'test.xml' contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<Accounts>
    <row>
        <FL val="Account Name">
            Company A
        </FL>
        <FL val="E-mail Address">
            mail@company-a.com
        </FL>
    </row>
    <row>
        <FL val="Account Name">
            Company B
        </FL>
        <FL val="E-mail Address">
            mail@company-b.com
        </FL>
    </row>
</Accounts>
</result>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier querying for the `<row>` elements,
then accessing the name through `$row->FL[0]` and the email through `$row->FL[1]`

```
$a = '//result/Accounts/row';

foreach ($xml->xpath($a) as $row){
    echo sprintf(
      "%s, %s<br>",
      $row->FL[0],  //name
      $row->FL[1]   //email
    );
}
```